# Solve rational ode function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'=\frac{-6c_1+9x+6y}{6c_1-6x-4y}$$

I am trying to solve this ODE where $c_1$ is a constant.

I tried change of variables $x=t+A$  , $y=s+B$

This lead to: $$dy/dx=\frac{9A+6B+(9t+6s-6c_1)}{-6A-4B+(-6t-4s+6c_1)}$$

after this point i am not to sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite as $$\frac{dy}{dx}(6c_1-6x-4y)=-6c_1+9x+6y\iff (6c_1-6x-4y)dy+(6c_1-9x-6y)dx=0$$
then this is an exact equation since $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (6c_1-6x-4y)=-6$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(6c_1-9x-6y)=-6$.

[Exact equations](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Exact.aspx) are ones of the form $Mdx+Ndy=0$ where $M_y=N_x$ (where $M$ and $N$ are "nice functions", e.g. at least $C^2$). This is because if $f(x,y)$ exists so that $f_x(x,y)=M$ and $f_y(x,y)=N$ then we have $$f_x+f_y\frac{dy}{dx}=0\implies \frac{d}{dx}f(x,y(x))=0\implies f(x,y)=c$$for some $c\in\Bbb R$. Under the assumption that $M$ and $N$ are nice (and $f$ is nice) we have $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$. Thus, $M_{y}=N_{x}$. So to solve these equations we integrate to find $f$ from the conditions $f_x=M$ and $f_y=N$, and then we have an implicit solution $f(x,y)=c$.

Comment: thank you but i dont understand why you have used partial derivatives and no i cant proceed as i am not familiar with this method.Thanks

Comment: Without using the method of exact equations I don't know how to solve this (at least without more careful thought). I suggest googling exact equations as this is a common method for solving problems like these.

Comment: i understand now thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be re-written in the form

$$ (-6c_1+9x+6y)\,dx+(-6c_1+6x+4y)\,dy=0$$

which is exact. So there is a solution of the form $f(x,y)=c$ where

1. $f(x,y)=\int(-6c_1+9x+6y)\,dx=-6c_1x+\frac{9}{2}x^2+6xy+c_2(y)$
2. $f(x,y)=\int(-6c_1+6x+4y)\,dy=-6c_1y+6cy+2y^2+c_3(x)$

Therefore the solution is

$$-6c_1(x+y)+\frac{9}{2}x^2+6xy+2y^2=c  $$

Comment: thanks was very helpful